# Can I change the layout direction to horizontal in the GDB TUI mode?

Tags: gdb

The default layout direction for the GDB TUI is up down e.g. src-win at top, asm-win at middle, cmd-win at bottom. Is there a way to change the direction in a horizontal style e.g. src-win at left, asm-win at middle, cmd-win at right?

Answer (score 0):

tui new-layout example {-horizontal src 1 asm 1} 2 status 0 cmd 1

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI-Commands.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

yes, follow by above answers:

when you are in gdb, just input above cmds:

```
(gdb)tui new-layout example {-horizontal src 1 asm 1} 2 status 0 cmd 1
```

then tui will create a layout name called `example`, then you can:

```
(gdb) tui # to enter tui mode
(gdb) layout example # to load the layout you just create
```